# Uniform Distribution: Probability that $X$ is rational

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

In Rosenthal's *A First Look At Rigorous  Probability Theory* one of the phrases about a random variable $X$ having a Uniform Distribution from $0$ to $1$ is the following:

> ...But now suppose we ask, what is the probability that $X$ is rational? ... More fundamentally, are all probabilites such as these necessarily even *defined* ?

The next part of the book then proves that there doesn't exist a definition of probability defined on all subsets in $[0,1]$ that satisfy "reasonable" properties.

However, I would argue that the above question: what is the probability that $X$ is rational, is defined, and equal to $0$.

My reasoning is that because the rational numbers are countable, then the subset of all rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ must also be countable (this follows from a proof I've done in real analysis that states a subset of a countable set is countable). Therefore, the probability that $X$ is rational is therefore $$P(X \in \Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1] ) = \sum_{r \in \Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1] } P(r) = 0$$

With the last equality holding because the probability of a single point in a continuous distribution is $0$ and the probability of a union of countably infinite disjoint events is the sum of the probability of each event.

Does my argument make sense? And if so, then what sort of subset in $[0,1]$ would it **not** be possible to define the probability that $X$ lies in the given subset?

Thanks for any clarification given.

Comment: A classical example of a non-measurable set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not *arguing against the question*, you merely have a (correct) answer for it: In the usual uniform probability measure on $[0,1]$, the measure of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is zero.

But merely that you know an answer doesn't invalidate *asking the question* in the first place. It looks like the book you're quoting from poses that question as a way to *motivate* developing measure theory rigorously instead of just getting by with hand-wavy intuition.

---

As Hans Lundmark notes in a comment, the classical example of a non-measurable set would be a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). All such examples are strange beasts that cannot be completely specified in finite space, because proving they exist requires the *axiom of choice*. (There are, under certain plausible conditions, models of standard set theory *except* the axiom of choice where all the subsets of $[0,1]$ that the model knows are in fact measurable -- but they can then be pretty weird in other ways).

Comment: So you're saying the question of $X$ being rational wasn't really meant to be related to the second question being asked? And the second question was to give more motivation to the idea of non-measurable sets? (Which will be a new topic for me)

Comment: @WaveX: No, I'm not saying that. Considering $[1,0]\cap\mathbb Q$ seems to me to be a perfectly reasonable motivation for asking "is such a probability even necessarily defined?" Just because _after_ asking the question we eventually end up _answering_ "yes, in this particular case the probability is defined" doesn't invalidate the _question_.

Comment: That last comment clears up a lot. Greatly appreciated